# Flutter: Pub Get or something else totally destroyed my App and reverting doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried reverting to builds I had yesterday. This should work, right? Nope.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Settings file 'C:\Users\xx-master\android\settings.gradle' line: 1
> - What went wrong: Could not compile settings file 'C:\Users\xx-master\android\settings.gradle'.
>
> > startup failed:   settings file 'C:\Users\xxmaster\android\settings.gradle': 1: unexpected token:
> > import @ line 1, column 1.
> > import 'dart:async';
> > ^
> > 1 error

When I look at my settings.gradle file, it has all my imports but between import and 'dart is red space...

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
```

The red space indicates:

> "identifier expected, got "package:geolocator/...'

All I was doing before this happened was trying out various libraries from pub dev. This is one of the more recent ones I tried out before this happened: https://pub.dev/packages/map_place/install

I did delete all the libraries I tried and I reverted my entire project to a build that worked in the morning.

Anybody know what happened and how to fix this?

Edit: For some reason, my settings.gradle is a mirror of my main.dart...

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all my android files and replaced it with a very old backup. Issue resolved. Still would like to know what happened though.